# How can I always capture the entire content of a network stream read in a single operation of an asynchronous read callback function?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcplistener

I have the following read callback function, in which I intend to read the entire contents of a TCP data transmission and perform work on those contents. It's working beautifully when reading any transmission of less than 8192 bytes. However, when it encounters a transmission of greater than 8192 bytes, it performs work on the first 8192 bytes, then runs the function again for the subsequent 8192 bytes. When I examine the `networkStream` object while stepping through the code it shows a `SystemNotSupported` exception; "This stream does not support seek operations."

I realize my exception handling sucks in the posted code. This is a sandbox test for now, not production code.

**I want to capture the entirety of the transmission in the callback function before the work is performed on the data. How can I do this?**

```
    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            {
                Client client = asyncResult.AsyncState as Client;
                if (client != null)
                {
                    NetworkStream networkStream = client.NetworkStream;                
                    int read;
                    try
                    {
                        read = networkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[read];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(client.Buffer, 0, data, 0, read);
                        string message = win1252.GetString(data).TrimEnd('\u001a', '\r', '\n'); //decode the transmission
                    //Do work on received message here...
                    } 
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                         return;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on any stream to return amount of data you've asked in `Read` request. This is especially true for remote streams (raw network, HTTP, remote file systems).

Easy solution is to wrap stream with `StreamReader` that will take care of properly handling partial reads from stream as well encoding.

Alternative solution - wrap another custom stream over network stream to read and buffer all data first (note that "all" in case of network stream may be hard to define).

Comment: Thanks @Alexei! Do you know of an example out there which demonstrates this? I understand the gist but I'm not immediately clear on how to implement it.

Comment: @DeeDee [StreamReader(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx) article has an example of constructing reader over stream. I don't have custom stream sample to merge multiple `Read` operations. It is more involved and likely be very confusing in your case as you'd need to build knowledge of "packet length" into stream...